# Code for writing dates re-occuring for a fiscal year?

Tags: oracle, date

I need code to automate my Oracle query, Dates for Fiscal Year.  I already have a piece of it but not sure how to write the beginning of the code.

```
BETWEEN SYSDATE AND add_months(SYSDATE, 1)
```

I need to write it so that it keeps the months APR - MAR, the part that will change is the year, giving that the fiscal year start in '15 and ends '16

Comment: APR - MAR doesn't look like a valid range (assuming the same fiscal year).

Comment: APR '15 thru MAR '16

Answer (score 0):

A good design would probably include a calendar table, so that you could map dates to fiscal months, months to quarters, and quarters to fiscal years.  So, you wouldn't write date logic to do it.  You'd join to your calendar table.

Keep in mind that your accountants may not always keep the same calendar, or may introduce different calendars for different sets of books.

That said, if you need SQL, there are lots of ways.  For example:

```
WITH report_parameters AS ( SELECT '2015' p_fiscal_year FROM DUAL ) 
SELECT ...
FROM   report_parameters, my_table
WHERE  my_table.my_date BETWEEN to_date('01-APR-' || p_fiscal_year,'DD-MON-YYYY') and add_months(to_date('31-MAR-' || p_fiscal_year,'DD-MON-YYYY'),12)+(86399/86400);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am not able to create tables, so I will try the SQL statement.  I do agree, if I were able to create my own table, it would be much easier.

Comment: I just noticed, I didn't extend the BETWEEN to the end of the day on 31-MAR.  I'll update.